# Unable to call another method after sendRedirect

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to call another method after sendRedirect call using servlet. I have also used return or response.setHeader("REFRESH","5;url=/Receive.jsp"); as in previous Srackoverflow answer. Is there any way to acheive this..?
it opens google page but doesnot /Receive page.

Basically i want to make mobile no verfication in which after entering mobile number it it will hit api link and return to new jsp page with otp textbox.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SignUp extends HttpServlet  {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
           String  mobno=request.getParameter("mobile");

                    response.sendRedirect("https://google.com");
                    response.setHeader("REFRESH", "5;url=/Receice.jsp"); 
        }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String mobno = request.getParameter("mobile");

        if (mobno.equals("")) {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("mob number can't be empty");
            out.flush();
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            RequestDispatcher myDispatch = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/OtpVerification.html");
            myDispatch.include(request, response);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("TextValue", mobno);
            doGet(request, response);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Receive.jsp");


        }
    }


}
    [here is the screen shot of the above code][1]
```

Comment: well what happens?

Comment: It is opening google page but doesnot  open Receive jsp page.

Comment: well that is your answer then.

Comment: maybe Filter can help. Lookup Filters

Comment: Okay going to use Filter .Thanks ..

Comment: I believe you trying to invoke a webservice. If that's the case then you are not on right track

Comment: The task is OTP verification..Please tell me from where to start from.

Comment: @himu Are you going to use Filters? If yes then can I post my answer below and can you accept it if you find it to be the solution? Thanks

Comment: @Faraz Durrani ..Of course. But after all i shifted to webservice implementation as per hhafeez. Thaks both of you for your promp and helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a Filter that intercepts calls to `google.com`

First, configure it in your web.xml file:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>SomeName123</filter-name>
<filter-class>packagename.FilterClassThatWillTakeCareOfTheSaidIssue</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>SomeName123</filter-name>   //name here should be exactly the same as above <filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/google.com</url-pattern> //play around with this google.com until you get it right
</filter-mapping>
```

After setting it up, now create a Filter class that implements `javax.servlet.Filter` and call it `FilterClassThatWillTakeCareOfTheSaidIssue` or whatever (the name has to be the same in the `<filter-class>` namespace in your web.xml), Override doFilter method, and then apply your logic there:

```
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
res.setHeader("REFRESH", "5;url=/Receice.jsp"); //This is your logic
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

And that should do it.